# When MediaPlayer is preparing to start, i want go back to "activity main" but my application is crash

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When MediaPlayer is preparing to start, i want go back to "activity main" but my application is crash.
I try this code, but not working :s

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {   
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null; 
            seekHandler.removeCallbacks(run, null);
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Whats the logcat error you receive?

Comment: system_process..  InputDispatcher     Dropped event because it is stale.

Comment: thats the only error in logcat?

Comment: i go back by my phone before mediaplayer do start, and my app crash

Comment: Are you using prepareAsync?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but try removing your seek callbacks before calling release.

You should add logcat output and the code where the error occurs to get better answers.

Comment: I used seekHandler.removeCallbacks(run, null) before mediaPlayer.release(), but nothing :s